# Accessing released version using Maven Release

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-release-plugin

I'm building a custom pipeline in Jenkins, where I'm invoking Maven Release plugin and I would need to store the released artifact version.
Command run on Jenkins:

```
sh 'mvn -Dusername=${GIT_USERNAME} -DskipTests -Darguments=-DskipTests --batch-mode clean release:clean release:prepare release:perform'
```

Artifact versions:

Prior to release: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Released: 0.0.1

After release: 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT

I would like to be able to store released versions "0.0.1" to be reused later in sh or Groovy script, how can I do that?

Comment: You could use the jenkins pipeline utitility `https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readmavenpom-read-a-maven-project-file` ... But you have to take care where you read the pom from because you want to read the release part which means you have to read `target/checkout/pom.xml` ??

Comment: is 'target/checkout/pom.xml" the pom file used for release? can you point me to some related documentation?

Comment: You see the output during the release process that there is an output where the checkout from the created tags is done which finall will create/deploy the release artifacts...

Answer (score 1):

You can get the version using the `help` plugin:

```sh
RESULT=$(mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout)
echo $RESULT
```

See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/evaluate-mojo.html

This will include the `-SNAPSHOT` suffix, so you'll need to remove that:

```sh
RESULT=$(mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout | sed s/-SNAPSHOT//)
echo $RESULT
```

Comment: I was already using the same strategy you proposed, but it feels more like a workaround (I wouldn't want to hardcode "SNAPSHOT" in my Jenkins pipeline)

Comment: You could also parse the new version out of the release.properties file.